# python discord bot wikipedia one command hindering all the others

Tags: python, bots, discord

I've found a code to make the bot look for important words on wikipedia but the problem is that if I put in in the code all the other commands stops working so i wanted to know what to do

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    words = message.content.split()
    if words[0].lower() == ".define":
       important_words = words[1:]
       try:
           await bot.send_message(message.channel, wiki_summary(important_words))
       except wikipedia.exceptions.DisambiguationError as e:
           await bot.send_message(message.channel, e)
```

I've thought of putting it to a @bot.command but don't really know how to modify it to get it to work and another problem was that in only takes up one word so if I want to look for 'city block' it would only take block and make it a disambiguation error
Thanks in advance for the help !

Comment: How have you determined that it "stops" other commands?

Comment: no other command work when i have this one in my code it doesn't react to the others